# Creating a CONSTANT with a STRING

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning,
I have a challenge in converting a string to a variable. I've set the CONSTANT's already on another page, on this page i need to first fetch a data in the database, then concatenate it with the other end of the constant, the collect eh value stored in the constant to be used on the current page.
Here is my code, i'll appreciate any assistance i can get. Thanks.

```
$sms_commission = strtoupper($upgrade_plan['plan_name'])."_SMS";
echo $sms_commission;
```

Each time i echo $sms_commission it gives GOLD_SMS instead of the value stored in it e.g 1000

Comment: Where is the constant in your code? you might need to post some more code, like where you are setting `$sms_commission` - it might perhaps be where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with [constant()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php), do:

```
echo constant($sms_commission);
```